# A black thing falls out of the USB port of my laptop

Tags: laptop, usb, thinkpad

My new laptop fan cooler's usb cable plug sucks a small black thing out of a usb port on my lenovo Thinkpad T400. That thing seems to be used for fixing the four pins inside the port. Without it, the connection is often loose,and there is often no detection of the devices.

I wonder if there is a solution for fixing the problem?

Is it a design problem of my new cooler, or a problem of my old laptop?
Although my laptop was purchases since 2009, it hadn't have that problem, until last month my new cooler's plug suck the black things out of two ports. Is it reasonable to ask for redemption from the cooler's seller or manufacturer?

The little black thing from a port:
[image]

A port with the little black thing:
[image]

Two ports without the little black things because the cooler usb plug suck them out:
[image]

Comment: That black tab helps prevent inverted insertion of the USB plug.  The USB receptacle is broken without it.

Comment: Yup, you've knackered the USB sockets on your laptop. If you have a sound, working port I would recommend you get a USB hub to connect your devices and if this breaks you can replace it rather than shell out loads to repair your laptop.

Comment: @sawdust: although my laptop was purchases since 2009, it hadn't have that problem, until last month my new cooler's plug suck the black things out of two recpetacles. Is it reasonable to ask for redemption from the cooler's seller or manufacturer?

Comment: @BigChris: Thanks. What does "shell out loads to repair your laptop" mean?

Comment: Shell out = pay. On-board USBs are almost always soldered directly onto the laptop motherboard and can be costly to repair/replace.

Comment: @BigChris: By "you can replace it", do you mean replace the receotacles, or the laptop? If the former, how can I replace it, by buying new recptors and diy, or by going to a repair shop?

Comment: Your photo clearly shows two broken on-board USB ports. These are not easy to repair. If your laptop has more USB ports that work then a USB hub will save these the same fate as the broken two. If the hub breaks then it's cheaper to buy a new hub than repair the next broken on-board USB sockets; leaving you with NO USB ports!

Comment: @BigChris: Understood. WHat are your recommendations for choosing a usb hub?

Comment: Any powered hub should suffice.

Comment: *"Is it reasonable to ask for redemption from the cooler's seller or manufacturer?"* -- You can try, but you'll have to prove that their product is defective.  They'll exchange the cooler, and it will be very difficult to get the T400 repaired at their expense.  That falls under the "consequential damages" exclusion of most products.  You have one remaining USB port on that T400; consider using a short USB extension cable (A-male to A-female).

Comment: It suck them because they broken... No USB plug will properly make contact, ever, again... in that port.

Comment: Not true. They were not broken before my new cooler. @FiascoLabs

Comment: Step #1, throw away the cooler.  Beyond that, I've looked for some sort of "USB repair" thingie that would permanently connect to a bad port and provide a reliable connection, but I've not found anything.  Probably best to take the unit to a computer repair shop and have them replace the ports -- I would assume that this is a fairly common repair.

Comment: (It sounds likely that the USB ports are of inferior quality and poor-quality plastic was used inside.)

Comment: @sawdust: Thanks. "You have one remaining USB port on that T400; consider using a short USB extension cable (A-male to A-female)." Do you mean that keep a extension cable connected to my laptop's only working usb port, in order to reduce the plug in and out to and from the port?

Comment: Probably use a USB cable feeding an external "hub", and then plug everything into the hub.

Comment: @BigChris Is a powered usb easier to carry with my laptop?

Answer (score 5):

That black plastic thing is a contact support block that is a single integral piece (both arrows) that the contacts insert into. Black on your USB sockets, white in image below:

[image]

If you give the USB plug inserted into this socket a good sideways push, it can snap the contact support block (top arrow) out of the socket.

Once this happens, the port is destroyed. Even if you insert the USB plug in the proper direction, the contacts have no support to ensure full, proper contact.

At this point, you've got a few options.

1. If the sockets are installed on the motherboard, you will have to do a full motherboard replacement (expensive)
2. If the manufacturer planned on users abusing their equipment, they may install the sockets on a small sub-board, you will have to replace that sub-board (less expensive)
3. If you know someone who has the skill to unsolder the socket, they (after much disassembly) may be able to desolder and reinstall the sockets. More or less expensive, a 2009 laptop may be worth less than the repair expense.

I would examine how you use the cooler and how its plug mounts. The most likely cause is that you use the combination of laptop and cooler in such a way that you keep hitting the USB plug, causing too much stress on the socket.

It's common when using stick type USB devices, to hit one of them and due to the leverage from the case length, snap the support block out.

Cable plugs tend to be a lot shorter and are less likely to break this piece as you're less likely to catch them just right.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix, if you have the loose plastic thing (black or white), try putting it in the way it should go, just before inserting USB plug.  It may provide needed support to the contacts. When you pull USB plug back out, you may need tweezers to retrieve little plastic thing.